# iTextSharp different results on Windows 7 vs Windows 8.1

Tags: itext

When I run the following code on Windows 7 and 8.1 I get different results. On Windows 7 if I re-run the code on the newly created file it throws exceptions while the Windows 8.1 code works fine.

Any Clues?????

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string a = @"C:\temp\Materials\20130911134612877_3.pdf";
            string b = @"C:\temp\Materials\20130911134612877_4.pdf";

            Program p = new Program();
            p.Open(a);
            p.SaveSource(b);

        }

        public List<Bitmap> Bitmaps { get; private set; }
        private string sourceFileName { get; set; }
        private string destPath { get; set; }
        public List<int> Source { get; set; }
        public List<int> Destination { get; set; }

        public void Open(string fileName)
        {
            this.sourceFileName = fileName;
            this.destPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), "Processed");
            if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(this.destPath);
            }
            string original = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName), "Orginal", Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            if (!File.Exists(original))
            {
                string originalPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(original);
                if (!Directory.Exists(originalPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(originalPath);
                }
                File.Copy(fileName, original);
            }

            if (this.Bitmaps != null)
            {
                for (int _i = 0; _i < this.Bitmaps.Count; _i++)
                {
                    this.Bitmaps[_i].Dispose();
                }
            }

            PDFDocument doc = GetDocument(fileName);
            this.Bitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();
            this.Source = new List<int>();
            this.Destination = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < doc.Count; i++)
            {
                this.Source.Add(i);
                this.Bitmaps.Add(doc.GetImage(i));
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
        public void SaveSource(string file)
        {
            if (this.Source.Count != 0)
            {
                PDFDocument pdf = new PDFDocument();
                pdf.FileName = file;
                foreach (int i in this.Source)
                {
                    pdf.Add(this.Bitmaps[i]);
                }
                pdf.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                if (File.Exists(this.sourceFileName))
                {
                    File.Delete(this.sourceFileName);
                }
            }
        }

        private PDFDocument GetDocument(string file)
        {
            PDFDocument doc = null;
            doc = new PDFDocument();
            doc.Open(file);
            return doc;
        }


        public static void MergePdfFiles(IEnumerable<string> files, string output)
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document doc;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy pdfCpy;

            doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
            pdfCpy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(doc, new System.IO.FileStream(output, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                // initialize a reader
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file);
                int pageCount = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // set page size for the documents
                doc.SetPageSize(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));

                for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pageCount; pageNum++)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage page = pdfCpy.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNum);
                    pdfCpy.AddPage(page);
                }

                reader.Close();
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    public class MyImageRenderListener : IRenderListener
    {
        public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }
        public void BeginTextBlock() { }
        public void EndTextBlock() { }

        public Bitmap Image = null;
        public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
        {
            try
            {
                PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
                if (image == null) return;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image.GetImageAsBytes()))
                {
                    Bitmap i = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
                    Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)i.Clone();
                    i.Dispose();
                    //                    int dpi = i.Height / 11;
                    int yDPI = Image.Height / 11;
                    int xDPI = (Image.Width * 2) / 17;

                    xDPI = Math.Abs(xDPI - 300) < 10 ? 300 : xDPI;
                    yDPI = Math.Abs(yDPI - 300) < 10 ? 300 : yDPI;
                    xDPI = Math.Abs(xDPI - 600) < 10 ? 600 : xDPI;
                    yDPI = Math.Abs(yDPI - 600) < 10 ? 600 : yDPI;

                    if (xDPI == yDPI)
                    {
                        Image.SetResolution(xDPI, yDPI);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                /*
                 * pass-through; image type not supported by iText[Sharp]; e.g. jbig2
                */
            }
        }
    }

    public class PDFDocument
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        ~PDFDocument()
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        public static void AddImage(Stream inputPdfStream, Stream outputPdfStream, Stream inputImageStream)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSize(1);

            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(inputImageStream);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(size.Width - 98, size.Height - 98);

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);

            int page = 1;

            //            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {

                PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = stamper.GetOverContent(page);

                pdfContentByte.AddImage(image);
            }
            stamper.Close();
        }

        public void Open(string fileName)
        {
            this.reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            this.parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
            this.listener = new MyImageRenderListener();

        }

        public int Count { get { return reader.NumberOfPages; } }

        public Bitmap GetImage(int index)
        {
            parser.ProcessContent(index + 1, listener);
            return listener.Image;
        }

        public Bitmap GetImage2(int index)
        {
            PdfDictionary page = reader.GetPageN(index + 1);
            return GetImagesFromPdfDict(page);
        }

        private PdfReaderContentParser parser = null;
        private MyImageRenderListener listener = null;

        private PdfReader reader = null;

        private Bitmap GetImagesFromPdfDict(PdfDictionary dict)
        {
            PdfDictionary res = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(dict.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)));
            PdfDictionary xobj = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(res.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)));
            Bitmap bm = null;
            if (xobj != null)
            {
                foreach (PdfName name in xobj.Keys)
                {
                    PdfObject obj = xobj.Get(name);
                    if (obj.IsIndirect())
                    {
                        PdfDictionary tg = (PdfDictionary)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(obj));
                        PdfName subtype = (PdfName)(PdfReader.GetPdfObject(tg.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)));
                        if (PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subtype))
                        {
                            int xrefIdx = ((PRIndirectReference)obj).Number;
                            PdfObject pdfObj = this.reader.GetPdfObject(xrefIdx);
                            PRStream str = (PRStream)(pdfObj);
                            iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject pdfImage = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject(str);

                            bm = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)pdfImage.GetDrawingImage();
                            bm.SetResolution(300.0f, 300.0f);
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (PdfName.FORM.Equals(subtype) || PdfName.GROUP.Equals(subtype))
                        {
                            GetImagesFromPdfDict(tg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return bm;
        }

        public void Split(string fileName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Save(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm, string filename)
        {
            Save(bm, filename, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
        }

        const float PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN = 0;
        const float PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN = 0;
        const float PAGE_TOP_MARGIN = 0;
        const float PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN = 0;

        public void Save(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm, string filename, System.Drawing.RotateFlipType rotate)
        {
            Bitmap image = bm;

            if (rotate != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                image.RotateFlip(rotate);
            }

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN, PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN, PAGE_TOP_MARGIN, PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN))
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, stream);
                    pdfDocument.Open();

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                    iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms);
                    img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.LETTER.Width - (PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN + PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN), PageSize.LETTER.Height - (PAGE_TOP_MARGIN + PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN));
                    pdfDocument.Add(img);

                    pdfDocument.Close();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Add(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm)
        {
            this.Add(bm, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone);
        }

        FileStream stream;
        iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDocument;
        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer;

        public void Add(System.Drawing.Bitmap bm, System.Drawing.RotateFlipType rotate)
        {
            if (this.stream == null)
            {
                this.stream = new FileStream(this.FileName, FileMode.Create);
                this.pdfDocument = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LETTER, PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN, PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN, PAGE_TOP_MARGIN, PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN);
                this.writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, stream);
                this.pdfDocument.Open();
            }

            Bitmap image = bm;

            if (rotate != RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipNone)
            {
                image.RotateFlip(rotate);
            }
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ms);
                img.ScaleToFit(PageSize.LETTER.Width - (PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN + PAGE_RIGHT_MARGIN), PageSize.LETTER.Height - (PAGE_TOP_MARGIN + PAGE_BOTTOM_MARGIN));
                pdfDocument.Add(img);
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (this.pdfDocument != null)
            {
                this.pdfDocument.Close();
                this.pdfDocument.Dispose();
                this.writer.Close();
                this.writer.Dispose();
                this.stream.Close();
                this.stream.Dispose();
                this.pdfDocument = null;
                this.writer = null;
                this.pdfDocument = null;
            }

            if (this.reader != null)
            {
                this.reader.Close();
            }

        }



        public void Tag(string oldFile, Stream fs, string text)
        {
            float x;
            float y;

            // open the reader
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
            float height = 60;
            float width = 150;
            x = size.Width - 40 - width;
            y = size.Height - height;
            Document document = new Document(size);

            // open the writer
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            document.Open();

            // the pdf content
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

            // create the new page and add it to the pdf
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
            cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

            cb.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
            cb.Fill();
            // close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)


            // write the text in the pdf content
            cb.BeginText();
            // select the font properties
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 20);
            // put the alignment and coordinates here
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, text, x + 5, y + 10, 0);
            cb.EndText();

            writer.Flush();
            document.Close();
            reader.Close();
            //          fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `When I run the following code on Windows 7 and 8.1 I get different results.` and `On Windows 7 if I re-run the code on the newly created file it throws exceptions...`  Can you elaborate on these points?

Comment: on windows 8.1 the ouput file matches the size of the input.

Comment: on windows 7 the output file is almost twice the size. The output file is readable be Foxit. but the above code throws an exception when I use the newly created file as the input.